# how to create the tab bar without app bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wish to add the tab app instead of app bar on my home screen. How to create it. Currently, my tab bar added at the bottom of app bar and I have removed the title and elevation. At the same time,  I can't say `appBar: null` as I need some space on the top of the tab bar.

```
Widget HomeTap = new Scaffold(

appBar: new AppBar(
bottom: new TabBar(

    indicatorColor: Colors.pinkAccent[100],
    labelColor: Colors.pinkAccent[100],
    indicatorWeight: 0.5,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey[400],
    tabs: [
      new Tab(text: 'Album',),
      new Tab(text: 'Artist'),
      new Tab(text: 'Playlist'),
      new Tab(text: 'Songs'),
      new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.search))
    ]),
title: null,
elevation: 0.0,
),
body: new TabBarView(
children: [
  new Center(
    child: new AlbumWidget(),
  ),
  new Container(),
  new Container(),
  new Container(),
  new Container(),
],
),
);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Flutter works with composition. You can pretty much replace any widget with something else. They are not limited to one specific child.

So you can simply do

```
new Scaffold(
   appBar: new TabBar(
      ...
   ),
   ...
)
```

The only requirement is for your widget to be of the right interface.
Scaffold requires as `appBar` a `PreferredSizeWidget`.

Fortunately, `TabBar` is already a `PreferredSizeWidget` by default. So no change needed

Comment: If we add `appBar: new TabBar` then where do I add the `TabBarView`. Currently, I have added to the body of Scaffold.

Comment: No change here. Still in Scaffold

Comment: when I do this the tabbar shows up right under the status bar. even though it is in a scaffold.

Comment: One shortcoming is that the color theme disappears

Answer (score 9):

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(

            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body:
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )

        ),
      ),
    );
```

## this worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Tried flexibleSpace?

```
return DefaultTabController(
length: 3,
child: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
  flexibleSpace: new Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(text: "Pending"),
          Tab(text: "Delivered"),
          Tab(text: "Rejected"),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
),
body: TabBarView(
  children: [
    PendingOrders(),
    DeliveredOrders(),
    RejectedOrders(),
  ],
   ),
   ),
 );
```