# Flutter TabBar Without AppBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a tabbed bar layout screen without the AppBar though. I have already referred to the solution on this link: [how to create the tab bar without app bar in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622103/how-to-create-the-tab-bar-without-app-bar-in-flutter) but it is not working for me. Here is what my screen looks like when I place TabBar in the `appbar:` parameter:

[image]

My TabBar has moved to the top left corner under the status bar and its all squeezed in one corner. It's almost as if it's not there at all.

When I use the AppBar class but only pass the `bottom:` parameter here is what happens:

[image]

There is an ugly space on top of the TabBar which is obviously meant for the AppBar title. Here is my code:

```
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new TabBar(
        tabs: widget._tabs.map((_Page page){
          return Text(page.tabTitle);
        }).toList(),
        controller: _tabController,
        isScrollable: true,

      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: widget._tabs.map((_Page page){
            return new SafeArea(
                top:false,
                bottom: false,
                child: (page.page == Pages.cart?new CartHomeScreen():_lunchesLayout())
            );
          }).toList()
      ),
    );
```

How can I just have TabBar without that space on top and is it possible to make the two tab items and their indicators to stretch and fill the side spaces?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Your first screenshot actually shows it working just fine - the issue is that 'fine' isn't quite what you expect. The default text color is white for tabbar, so your labels aren't showing and instead just the bottom line is, which is what you see at the top left. Also, TabBar is a preferred size widget already, but it doesn't have the same height as an AppBar so if that's what you're going for, it won't look like it.

Here's an example that makes it look like the app bar. `kToolbarHeight` is the same constant that AppBar uses.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'msc',
      home: new DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
            child: new Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: new SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(child: new Container()),
                    new TabBar(
                      tabs: [new Text("Lunches"), new Text("Cart")],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[new Text("Lunches Page")],
              ),
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[new Text("Cart Page")],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which results in this:

[image: Screenshot showing tabbed app bar]

Edit:

As noted in the comments and from [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17459#issuecomment-387984398), you could also use the flexibleSpace property of the AppBar to hold the tabbar to basically the same effect:

```
return new DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          new TabBar(
            tabs: [
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: can you please explain to give tabbar some elevation or shadow effect to look like an appbar ?

Comment: @JayMungara if you look at [the source code of appbar](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d200dc150bb069ff7ec6c50c00d25f2b1a3ed631/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart#L596) you'll see they use a `Material` with the elevation property set to show a shadow. You can do the same - it would probably be easiest to replace the container with a `Material` and set the elevation the same way. If you have problems with that, it seems like a candidate for a new question.

Answer (score 50):

Follow below code

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Tabbar with out Appbar",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              labelColor: Colors.red,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: '1st tab',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: '2 nd tab',
                )
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Container(child: Center(child: Text('people'))),
                  Text('Person')
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

view the result

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what I need. Thank you. But remember to dispose of `tabController`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate you!

Answer (score 14):

I take the code from rmtmckenzie but only to create a widget without material app

```
return new DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
          child: new Container(
            height: 50.0,
            child: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car,color: Colors.grey,)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit,color: Colors.grey)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike,color: Colors.grey)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I get 'bottom overflowed by 2 pixel'

Answer (score 13):

You won't need to use `appBar` property:

```dart
DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        TabBar( // <-- Your TabBar
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.call)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView( // <-- Your TabBarView
            children: [
              Container(color: Colors.blue),
              Container(color: Colors.red),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: You might need to set tab controller to both!!!

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal Yes. You can also use `DefaultTabController`.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `toolbarHeight` property in `AppBar` widget with `kMinInteractiveDimension` value as shown below:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: kMinInteractiveDimension,
    bottom: TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      tabs: [], // your tab bars
    ),
  ),
  body: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: [], // your tab views
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Directly use `TabBar` in `appBar` property:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.call)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.message)),
        ],
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          Center(child: Text('Call')),
          Center(child: Text('Message')),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the flexiblespace prop and not the bottom prop of the appBar.
All in the safeArea widget and you can add some vertical padding.

```
home: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                flexibleSpace: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.1)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.2)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.3)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.1),
                  Icon(Icons.2),
                  Icon(Icons.3),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 4):

From CopsOnRoad's answer, I've created a hidden TabBar like this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      TabBar( // <-- Hidden TabBar
        indicator: BoxDecoration(),
        tabs: [
          SizedBox.shrink(),
          SizedBox.shrink(),
        ],
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: TabBarView( // <-- Your TabBarView
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.blue),
            Container(color: Colors.red),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, all what you have to provide is `height` to your `TabView`.

Here is a simple example. You can either use `DefaultTabController` or `TabController`. In order to fully customizable, I'll use `TabController`.

`_getTabBar` function return list of tabs.

```
  TabBar _getTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      tabs: <Widget>[
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.redAccent)),
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.redAccent)),
      ],
      controller: tabController,
    );
  }
```

`_getTabBarView` take list of widgets as input argument and creates a tab view.

```
  TabBarView _getTabBarView(tabs) {
    return TabBarView(
      children: tabs,
      controller: tabController,
    );
  }
```

`SafeArea` is used to move content below status bar. `_getTabBarView` is wrapped with a `Container` so that we can allocate a height. This is one way of allocating height, you can use some other way also.

So here is the full code, wrap within a `MaterialApp` and you have got a fully customizable tab bar and view. life-cycle methods are used to create and dispose `TabController`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabControllerScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TabControllerScreenState createState() => _TabControllerScreenState();
}

class _TabControllerScreenState extends State<TabControllerScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  TabBar _getTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      tabs: <Widget>[
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.redAccent)),
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.redAccent)),
      ],
      controller: tabController,
    );
  }

  TabBarView _getTabBarView(tabs) {
    return TabBarView(
      children: tabs,
      controller: tabController,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _getTabBar(),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              child: _getTabBarView(
                <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.home),
                  Icon(Icons.settings),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. This is a widget, without any scafold or material app around it, so make sure you provide that tree yourself. Otherwise it's ready for copy-paste

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      TabBar(controller: _tabController, tabs: const [
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cookie_outlined)),
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.no_food))
      ]),
      Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
        Container(color: Colors.greenAccent),
        Container(color: Colors.yellowAccent)
      ]))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `TabBar` inside `AppBar` in its `flexibleSpace` property.

Answer (score 1):

Give toolbarHeight : 0 for Appbar

```
appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 0, // <--- Add this line to app bar
      bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
        Tab(
          text: "Transactions",
        ),
        Tab(
          text: "Transfer",
        )
      ]),
    ),
```

[image: See No App Bar]

Answer (score 0):

## Recommended method using toolbarHeight property

By setting the toolbarHeight property of a AppBar to zero will remove them toolbar and leaving the tabbar at the bottom as set by theme.

```
Scafford(
    appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 0,
        bottom: TabBar(...)
    )
)
```