# How to create a custom tabBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to implement a custom scrollable TabBar in my body, not in the appBar

[image]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i tried some solution but i cant find a solution |

Comment: I think I am going to make a package for what you want later this week because I need it too, but check out my solution using pageView below!

Comment: Also, I think this is worth checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609252/flutter-tabbar-without-appbar?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PageView and PageController**

So this isn't exactly what you are looking for, instead of bottom bar you could do a horizontal scroll (scrollView), but I hope this pushes you in the right direction. This code basically uses `pageView` to display pages, and since there is a page controller you can animate any button or `onPress` to a specific page.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TestWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Tab Bar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[ 
            Expanded(
              flex: 10,
              child: ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pageController.animateToPage(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
                    },
                    child: Text("One",),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pageController.animateToPage(1, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
                    },
                    child: Text("Two",),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pageController.animateToPage(2, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
                    },
                    child: Text("Three",),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 40,
              child: PageView(
                controller: _pageController,
                children: [
                  Text("Page One"),
                  Text("Page Two"),
                  Text("Page Three")
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This basically allows you to use any tab bar or buttons you wont to switch page while keeping swipe functionality :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a `listView` that scrolls horizontally, then build up thous `ListTile` elements, and make them clickable. If you want to swipe then add on a `gesturedetector`.

Comment: what about TabController ?? i want a custom tabBar not just List view

Comment: if you mean the dragable functionality with "TabController" then you can use GestureDragStartCallback see this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureDragStartCallback.html and you can add a function to change the page, when the pointer is dragging horizontaly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom list with the same view. Here is the sample code

```
ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (_, count) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.green),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      print("You clicked");
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      list[count],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: list.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            )
```

Comment: if it is possible i prefer using flutter TabController and TabBar

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "NestedScrollView" and put the information outside the tabbar in "flexibleSpace"